# convert 24Bit per pixel to 8 bit tiff

Tags: image, image-processing, image-manipulation, tiff

i want to convert a 24 bit per pixcel(Rgb) int 8 bit per pixel tiff image is there any code to convert please share or tell me the algo in c sharp

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean how do you turn a RGB image into a greyscale one?  A simple perceptually-based method is to transform it into [YIQ colorspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ) and discard the chroma information.  You can generate the luminance portion by this equation:

```
 l = (0.299*r) + (0.583*g) + (0.114*b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial with C# code:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale

Disclaimer: I work at Atalasoft.

If you are interested in a commercial solution, you can do this with [DotImage](http://atalasoft.com/products/dotimage).  The code to convert a single framed tiff is

```
AtalaImage img = new AtalaImage("file.tif");
img = img.GetChangedPixelFormat(PixelFormat.Pixel8bppGrayscale);
img.Save("gray.tif", new TiffEncoder(), null);
```

If you have multipaged TIFFs, you just need to loop through them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean you want to convert from a 24 bit colour image to an 8 bit colour image, then you'll need to look into dithering algorithms.

A very simple dithering algorithm is described on this page: http://wwwhome.cs.utwente.nl/~schooten/graphics/
It's not very high quality, but it's easy to understand as a first attempt.

After that, have a go at the Floyd-Steinberg dithering algorithm.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering